# Check if another Thread is interrupted, without polling

Tags: java, multithreading

I'd like to check to see if a Thread is Interrupted, from some other Thread, without polling this to check - i.e. some kind of monitor.

Specifically, what I am trying to do is force-kill (Stop) a Thread when it is Interrupted. I will include a code example below of a trivial example of what I have done so far - it works, but polling to check if the Thread is interrupted is sub-optimal and I would like to avoid this.

```
public class ThreadTest
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        final Thread outerThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Need to externally monitor the thread to detect and process interrupts (for cancellation)
                final Thread thread = Thread.currentThread();

                new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            }
                            catch (final InterruptedException e)
                            {}

                            if (thread.isInterrupted())
                            {
                                // Then kill it
                                thread.stop();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();

                uninterruptibleForever();
            }
        };

        outerThread.start();

        // Ensure the thread has time to start up
        Thread.sleep(500);

        outerThread.interrupt();

        // The thread should terminate at this point and not continue.
    }

    /** Some arbitrary task that runs forever and ignores interrupts */
    public static void uninterruptibleForever()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("I''m still running at {0}", new Date().toLocaleString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't check without polling. "Check" and "poll" both mean the same thing.

Comment: Ditto what persixty said. If your program calls `thread.stop()`, then your program is _broken_. You haven't told us what `uninterruptableForever()` does or why it is uninterruptable, but you can not solve your problem with `thread.stop()`. Find another way.

Answer (score 2):

I can't recommend strongly enough that you don't use `Thread#stop()`.
It should never have existed, was deprecated very quickly and frankly should have been removed about 20 years ago.

You have no idea what the thread is doing when you stop it and it is very easy to corrupt shared objects and leave external resources (e.g. files) in an invalid state.

Suppose the thread is in the middle of resizing a shared `ArrayList<>` there's risk the object will be corrupted and your whole program fails intermittently in ways you cannot fix.

Do not use `Thread#stop()` it is broken and cannot be fixed.

It's a terrible feature of Java that it leads people into invalid techniques regarding threads.

---

Caveat over - how about just overriding `interrupt()` in a sub-class?

```
    public void interrupt(){
        this.stop(); 
    }
```

You've decided to sub-class `Thread` (rather than `Runnable`) so this will "work". "work" in the sense of what you're doing. Not actually work or anything.

The only valid way to solve this is have the thread you want to terminate co-operate by responding to `interrupt()` as an instruction to come to a suitable point and then terminate cleanly.
Or you can create another flag indicating the thread should end.

Comment: My actual use case requires a callable (I just went for a Thread for a smaller example), so override interrupt would not be possible.

Comment: If you can't get notified of a call to `interrupt()` then I suppose the answer is 'You can't'. But whatever you're doing, `Thread#stop()` is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need to monitor the thread externally. But here is a small sample how you could do it if you really need it:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public abstract class MonitoredCallable implements Runnable {

    private final List<InterruptedHandler> interruptedHandlers = new LinkedList<>();

    protected abstract void runInternal() throws Exception;

    @Override
    public final void run() {
        try {
            runInternal();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
        }
        for (InterruptedHandler interruptedHandler : interruptedHandlers) {
            interruptedHandler.threadInterrupted(this);
        }
    }

    public void addInterruptedHandler(InterruptedHandler interruptedHandler) {
        this.interruptedHandlers.add(interruptedHandler);
    }

    public static interface InterruptedHandler {
        void threadInterrupted(Thread t);
    }
}
```

Now just use it like this:

```
MonitoredThread mt = new MonitoredThread() {
    @Override
    protected void runInternal() throws Exception {
         //dosomething

    }
};
mt.addInterruptedHandler(t->t.stop());
```

Comment: The implementation you've suggested appears to be polling just like the example I have already?

Comment: No, it isn't! The idea is to let the Thread notify the `InterruptedHandler`s when the Thread gets interrupted, so no polling there. Take a look at `Observer` Pattern here (http://www.baeldung.com/java-observer-pattern)

Comment: updated my answer to use a runnable instead of thread - as stated in your comment